# php - T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Tags: php

I've been staring at this code for ages, and can't seem to figure out where I included the extra space. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''includes.php ?> ' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in C:\wamp\www\cas_project_final\includes\header.php on line 3

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<?php include 'includes/head.php'; ?>
<body>
    <?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
    <div id="container">
        <?php include 'includes/aside.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Maybe in one of the includes? In header.php on line 3 to be precise. At least, that's what the message says, but often it can be on the line before.

Comment: ^ funny that, php error messages are quite good